# How to set dynamic range in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, range

I am using a range for 5 Employee ID with name of "EmpIDS" and it is working fine, but whenever I am adding a new one I have to set the range again, I think it can be done dynamically, so that the range "EmpIDS" will automatically set the value itself, like-> If I add 5 more rows it will have total 10 values.

Comment: Yes just make it dynamic using counta for example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can do it using Counta with Offset and entering this in 'Refers to' when you define the named range:

```
=OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,0,0,COUNTA(Sheet1!$A:$A))
```

or I prefer to use Index:

```
=Sheet1!$A$1:INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$A,COUNTA(Sheet1!$A:$A))
```

[See this tutorial](https://exceljet.net/lessons/how-to-create-a-dynamic-named-range-with-index)

Assumes there are no empty cells in the range - if there are, Counta will give the wrong result, in which case you can substitute

```
MATCH("zzzzzz",Sheet1!$A:$A)
```

for Counta with text values, or

```
MATCH(9E+99,Sheet1!$A:$A)
```

for numeric values.